# The resource could not be resolved. (DynamicResource)

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, warnings, dynamicresource

I used [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123460/Simplest-Way-to-Implement-Multilingual-WPF-Applica) to implement a multilingual WPF application. Everything compiles, runs and works. But there is a problem: whenever I try to refer to a DynamicResource:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{DynamicResource subtimer}" />
```

Visual Studio (2015) shows me a warning: **The resource could not be resolved**. It does not prevent working but it is just annoying and distracting (50 warnings for my smallest app).

Comment: Merge the english ( or whichever is most commonly used ) resource dictionary in app.xaml. Then merge whichever language version the user chooses into application resources.

Comment: Thank you! I only merged the English resource dictionary in app.xaml, and the problems went away. Still, could you please show how to do the next one? Maybe, I have done it already following the tutorial from the link but just don't know about it.

Comment: The tutorial merges into the window, which is a bad idea. Application resources are the way forward. Probably. They have scope, so you could actually merge a resourcedictionary into a window or panel's resources and just replace your localised strings inside that scope (Window or panel).